# MS Access form with next row value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have form with column diameter (A). I need to make another column with diameter from next row (B) and third column (C)with substraction of columns A,B.

```
        A       B       C
line1   11     
line2   14      11      3
line3   16      14      2
line4   24      16      8
```

I cannot use query with sub-query because Access does not allow editting recordset when using subquery and I need to use checkbox. I am also filtering data, so when I filter line1 and line 3, it gives me:

```
        A       B       C
line1   11     
line3   16      14      2
```

I don't get right value in column B, so substraction is not correct. Is it possible to work with data in continuous form like in Excel and make function for fields to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: are your records autonumbered to keep them in a specific sequence?  Does your logic apply to all records, or is there another key field that links the various records?

Comment: so when you filter, line 3 value should have value of 11 right?  How are you filtering?  Have you tried iteration through your filtered records, and remember the previous value of A in order to calculate your A - A(previous) to get your C value.  (it sounds like B is not really required, as your main goal is to calculate C right?)